# Understanding the Address location denoted by Qword ptr?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, intel-pin

I encountered a following assembly instruction `and rax, qword ptr [0xff5ff098]`

What i want to know is what is memory address which will be accessed in the following instruction.
Will the memory address `0xff5ff098` be zero extended  or will it be extended by most significant bit ?

In `Intel Pin` tool the api `IARG_MEMORYREAD_EA` is giving it as extended by 1 i.e. it is giving the following address `0xffffffffff5ff098` . Is this address a possible address  ?

I am working on a 64 bit machine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there was a question within the past year about whether 32-bit absolute addresses were zero or sign extended, but this probably isn't an exact duplicate anyway.  I seem to recall Jester answered it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How is it encoded?  RIP-relative or absolute?

If absolute, it's using the sign-extended-disp32 addressing mode (because [32-bit displacements in addressing modes are *always* sign extended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34058400/224132), even when there are no registers involved).

If it's RIP-relative, then your disassembler should be showing you the correct final address, calculated from RIP + rel32.

Either your disassembler or PIN are showing it incorrectly, since if it's really sign-extended to 64-bit, your disassembler should be showing you that.

---

And yes, both RIP-relative and absolute addressing are possible in x86-64.

x86-32 had two redundant ways to encode `[disp32]` addressing modes with no registers.  x86-64 repurposes the shorter one as RIP-relative, and leaves the longer one as `[sign-extended-disp32]` absolute addressing.

I'll use NASM syntax for an example.  You can use `default rel` to use RIP-relative by default, and you can override on a case-by-case basis like this:

```
  MOV     RAX, [abs FS:_start]    ; _start just as something that assembles
  MOV     RAX, [rel FS:_start]    ; RIP-rel for thread-local is usually not useful!

 64 48 8b 04 25 b5 00 40 00   mov rax,QWORD PTR fs:0x4000b5
 64 48 8b 05 e7 fe ff ff      mov rax,QWORD PTR fs:[rip+0xfffffffffffffee7]  # 4000b5 <_start>
```

---

> Is this address a possible address ?

Yes, addresses in the upper half of the canonical range are used. e.g. `less /proc/self/maps` shows that Linux maps the `vsyscall` page it exports into high address space:

```
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Canonical address means that bits `[63:48]` are copies of bit 47.  i.e. the address is what you would get from sign-extending the low 48 bits.  Non-canonical addresses will always fault on current hardware, so if you want to implement something like tagged pointers with those redundant bits, you still have to redo the sign-extension before dereferencing.

---

Note that `qword ptr` tells you the operand-size, not anything about how the addressing mode is encoded.